# Is there a way in R to create summary statistics table from a list of data

Tags: r, list, statistics, summary

I am trying to make a summary table of my data using table1::table1 function.

I can get the below code to work as expected.

```r
DF = list('A' = rnorm(100, mean = 1),
          'B' = rnorm(100, mean = 2),
          'C' = rnorm(100, mean = 3))
table1::table1(~A+B+C, data=DF, overall = 'List 1')
```

I am trying to do the same thing as above but instead, I have a list of data that I want to combine and have the columns as List 1 and List 2, with the same summary statistics from A, B, C as the rows.

```r
DF = NULL
DF[['List 1']] = list('A' = rnorm(100, mean = 1),
          'B' = rnorm(100, mean = 2),
          'C' = rnorm(100, mean = 3))

DF[['List 2']] = list('A' = rnorm(100, mean = 1),
          'B' = rnorm(100, mean = 2),
          'C' = rnorm(100, mean = 3))
```

Does anyone have any suggestions or know of a better way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `transpose` from `purrr` and `flatten` or `unlist` the `list` elements to be a `list` of 3

```
library(purrr)
DF2 <- transpose(DF) %>% 
            map(flatten_dbl)
```

NOTE: `DF` is the second dataset in the OP's post

Now, we test with `table1`

```
table1::table1(~A+B+C, data=DF2, overall = 'List 1')
```

-output

[image]

---

If we need to create a two column table, convert the `list` of `list` of vectors to a single `data.frame` while creating a column with the `names` of the outer `list` element

```
new_DF <- do.call(rbind, Map(cbind, nm1 = names(DF), 
         lapply(DF, as.data.frame)))
row.names(new_DF) <- NULL

table1::table1(~ A + B + C |nm1, data = new_DF)
```

-output

[image]

Comment: Thank you, but I am looking to have List 1 as one column and List 2 as another